# How do I write a loop that concatenates my data with a word?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of words in Column A. All I want to do is add the word "MASTER" to each word and copy and paste it to another column. Here's what I have that isn't working. How do I correct my loop to make it work.

```
function myJoin() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sh0 = sheet1.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sh0.getLastRow();
   var range = sh0.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1);\\destination row

  var range2 = sh0.getRange(1,2,lastRow,1).getValue();\\my data

  for(var i=0;i<=lastRow;i++){
 

    range.setValue(range2[i]+"MASTER");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myJoin() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');//my sheet 0 was something else
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  let vA = vs.map(r => {
    return [r[0] + "Master"]
  });
  sh.getRange(1, 2, vA.length, vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

[Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)